# Change Which FeatureClass a RelationshipClass Points at

Tags: esri-geodatabase, coordinate-system, attribute-table, ms-access, relationship-class

When you use ArcGIS' Project tool it creates a new featureclass.  This is awesome, unless the featureclass you projected had been related to twenty-some tables.  All of those relationships still point to the original featureclass, but not the new one, as described in this [ESRI article](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=project_%28data_management%29).  So, does anyone know if there is a good way to point an existing relationship class at a different featureclass without deleting the relationship class?

Comment: On further investigation, I realize that I only have to change one relationship per featureclass in this specific case.  But I would still like an answer, because I do have the same situation in other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of mocking with the gdb tables (which is an unsupported option), you have to delete the relationship classes and recreate them. You can do so manually or with a script, but the delete/create cycle still needs to happen.

Comment: Well, yes, my question didn't specify that I wanted to do this without deleting the relationship class.  I will clarify.

Comment: "[..]to point an existing relationship class at a different featureclass **without deleting the relationship class**?"

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: You cannot "reassign the relationship without deleting it". FYI I maintained the ESRI GeoDatabase relationship code for 3 years.

Comment: Thanks, @Ragi Yaer Burhum